# Comparing 2 tables with Limited join options

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this category group , which has 5 categories and Description(Display Text)of the categories . Fields(Category ID, Display Text)

And I have another view which has information about like Month,Gender,New(employee in Department),Transfer(Employee From another department) and Continuing(Same department) and Category ID .

Now I want to check if for each categoryID in the category table, if there are any New,transfer or Continuing according to the Gender and month.

For example, CategoryID =1 , Check in the view if there is any CategoryID=1 present then return all the details of the ID in the VIEW , If not just return 0 for every Gender and Month.

### @EDIT:

```
    select c.UniqueID, 
           c.DisplayText ,  
           s.Gender, 
           s.Term,
           s.Status ,
           s.NoofStatus 
     from Category c 
     left outer Join 
     Status_Count_View s on c.UniqueID=s.UniqueID
```

I want all the Records in Table A to be mapped on to Table B for every Term.. If no records in Table B are found for a particular Category in Table A still that Category has to be displayed with a value 0

Comment: What is the question?  Do you have any SQL for this that we could look at?

Comment: @snp.it Edit your question instead of writing code in comment.

Comment: What does "limited JOIN options" mean in the title?  It's not mentioned anywhere in the post.

Comment: I only have the UniqueID(ON Category table and on View) so I cannot get info according to the Month. Say , Month ='January', I want all the categories(Category Table) displayed and info from the view joined on top of it.If categoryID does not have any info in the view then return 0.

Comment: How do I repeat CategoryID's for every month. For Example, Category_Table(where CategoryID= 1,2,3) and Month_Table(Month= jan,Feb,march,April)... I want to display both in one table like       Table= (Jan,1;Jan,2;Jan,3;Feb,1;Feb,2;Feb,3;March,1;March,2;March,3;April,1;April,2;April,3)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from category c, cat_view cv where c.Cat_ID = cv.categoryID
union
select c.cat_id, c.DisplayText, 0 , 0 ,'',0,0,0
from category c 
where c.Cat_ID not in (select distinct(categoryID) from cat_view)
```

Please edit column names according to your need. Key here is 'union'. First we get everything that matches. Then we get all category which doesn't match and add those into result (achieved by 'union' keyword).

Comment: The above example is same like left outer Join.......and when I have a parameter Term, Then all the categories in the Category table dont show up, only for the ones it has values to shows up